# What is the time complexity of mapping a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, maps

I have a map of int to a vector,

```
map<int,vector<int>> m
```

Suppose I map N elements to x.

Now when i write, **vector v = m[x]**

What is the time complexity of mapping a vector. Is it O(1) because of iterators or O(N)!

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(logN) to find the key and O(N) to copy the vector, however the actual time complexity would be asymptotic in nature and should be much better than O(NlogN) in performance.

Hence, the time complexity is Big-Oh (NlogN).

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting a value from a `std::map` is O(log N).

Note that in addition to that you take a value copy of the `map` value, perhaps

```
const vector& v = m[x];
```

would be better?

Comment: Yepp. Mentioned in the doc. [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at): _Logarithmic in the size of the container._

Comment: What if I use unordered_map ? Will it be O(1) !

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is a binary tree. As such, a single element lookup is O(log N) complexity.

But in addition to that, in your case `vector` copying will take place, which is O(N) complexity.

However, the *N* in the first expression is the number of *keys* in the map, and is not the same *N* from the second expression, where it represents the size of the *value*.

Assuming both *N*'s are of the same magnitude, the overall complexity would be O(N*logN).